# what does it mean about that sybase error

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq, sybase-asa, sybase-ase15

it is about sybase Insufficient account permissions？
[sybiq@db ~]$ isql -U abc -P abc -S abc3

```
1> sp_spaceused
2> go
Msg 504, Level 11, State 0:
SQL Anywhere  -265:  'sp_spaceused'


1> select @@version
2> go
 @@version                                                                                                                        
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Sybase IQ/15.4.0.3038/140813/P/ESD 4.5/Enterprise Linux64 - x86_64 - 2.6.18-194
         .el5/64bit/2014-08-13 16:59:08                    

(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sp_iqspaceused command is ok。
that can not search from the internet.